# click one prime ng Radio Buttons in a Form Array affect all Radio Buttons in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

**Behavior**

check on one radio button in a group of FormArray checks all other radio buttons in other groups. As this is a Form Array all the formControlName values for the radio buttons are the same.

**Expected behavior**
When selecting a radio button in one group in a Form Array it should have no impact on the radio buttons in another group.

**Minimal reproduction of the problem**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-radio-form-array-selection-issue-rmeptx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Your stackblitz code is not working, it is throwing some errors.

Comment: issue fixed. its working fine now @VimalPatel

Comment: Hello, @SaadKhan, I have the same problem, how have you solve the problem?

Comment: @Alba the issue is related to compatibility of angular 11 with ng prime. I used Mat-radio button instead to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the radio buttons across the form array having the same value.  I found an (ugly) work around that uses ngModel and the onClick event.  Also note the ngModelOptions which is required to use ngModel inside a FormGroup

```js
public userAgree: boolean = null;

updateUserAgreeFormControl() {
  if (this.reportCommentFormGroup)  
    this.reportCommentFormGroup.get('userAgree').setValue(this.userAgree);
}
```

```html
<span class="radio-button">
    <p-radioButton name="userAgree" label="Agree" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="userAgree"      
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (onClick)="updateUserAgreeFormControl()"></p-radioButton>
</span>
```